# FileNotFoundException exists in both System.IO and System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I've started a simple new ASP.NET Core web project which needs to read the contents of files.

In a new **Class Library (Package)** (Visual C# > Web) project, which by default targets the following frameworks. I've added `System.IO.FileSystem` also.

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": { },
  "dotnet5.4": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    }
  }
}
```

In one of my classes, I am trying to throw a `FileNotFoundException` but I get the following error against *.NET Platform 5.4*:

> **CS0433** The type 'FileNotFoundException' exists in both 'System.IO, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I've tried removing the reference to `System.Runtime` but this is futile as `System.IO.FileSystem` itself lists it as a dependency.

This only seems to manifest itself when building against .NET Platform 5.4 as seen here:

[image: VS2015 screenshot]

And the offending code:

```
if (!File.Exists(file))
    throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException();
```

**Have I misconfigured my project dependencies? Is there an alternative IO namespace I should be using?**

Comment: use the full name in your code. throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException ...

Comment: Tried that, same error appears.

Comment: Can you update your question with your dependencies section?  I suspect one of your dependencies is a full .net 4.5 library doesn't have a .net core port yet. in this case you have to add it to `"net451`: { "dependencies" : { ... }` rather than to the global dependencies section

Comment: Also, why are you referencing `"System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0" in dotnet5.4 section anyways? it doesn't seem to be a .net core assembly at all

Comment: http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/ do not list the FileSystemException inside System.IO.FileSystem. Using rc1 or nightly rc2 builds of asp.net core

Comment: @Tseng I'm referencing `System.IO.FileSystem` as this provides various IO classes including `File`, `Path`, etc. Should I be using something else?

Comment: @Tseng All dependencies are already listed above in the `project.json` snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I misconfigured my project dependencies? Is there an alternative IO namespace I should be using?

You have misconfigured your project dependencies. The error message tells us that much. There is not an alternative IO namespace to use. Rather, you need to reconfigure your project dependencies to avoid naming collisions.

## Option 1, Stick with RC1 and specify compatible dependencies

**global.json** > target RC1 of the SDK.

```
"sdk": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
}
```

**project.json** > change the dependencies to be compatible. It turns out that the `4.0.0` versions of `System.IO` and `System.Runtime` are compatible whereas the betas you were using are not.

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": { },
  "dotnet5.4": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
      "System.IO": "4.0.0",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

## Option 2, Upgrade to RC2 and use NET Standard Platform

If you are ready to target the RC2 SDK, then you can target a specific .NET Platform Standard. Here is an example that targets the `rc2-20221` SDK and `netstandard1.3`.

**global.json** > target RC2 of the SDK.

```
"sdk": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-20221"
}
```

project.json > use the `netstandard` to ensure a compatible API surface area.

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*"
},
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.3": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
    },
    "imports": [
      "net451",
      "dotnet5.4"
    ]
  }
}
```

## Test Harness

This is a small program that is building and running on my machine. It works using either option 1 or option 2.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException();
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```